# Ionic Side Menu on enter and leave (show / hide)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I'm trying to listen to when [ionic-side-menu](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/) are opened and closed. To do this I am attaching the `$ionicView.enter` and `$ionicView.leave` like so:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function(){
  console.log('leave called');
});

$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){
  console.log('enter called');
});
```

Using this code `$ionicView.enter` is called once when the app loads and never again when toggling the menu. `$ionicView.leave` also never gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$ionicSideMenuDelegate.isOpen()` to keep track of opening and closing of the side menu:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return $ionicSideMenuDelegate.isOpen(); }, function(isOpen) {
    if (isOpen) {
        // Menu Opened
    }
    else {
        // Menu Closed
    }
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1437